# Coding union-find in 4-connectivity two-pass algorithm

Tags: c++, image-processing, data-structures

I try to code in c++ a component labelling code uses two pass algorithm with 4-connectivity. You might want to see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling. In that algorithm there is a data structure named as union-find. I cannot get the structure of that and cannot code it since I cannot understand how the algorithm is using that structure.
Do you know how to use union-find in that algorithm or at least Is there any native library in C++ environment or do you know any source to understand that structure. Maybe an animation might be useful.

Comment: This can be found at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14347065/2d-array-neighboring-algorithm/14350691#14350691

Answer (score 1):

The data structure of Union-Find is also called a "disjoint-set". You can actually find some more descriptions and information of disjoint-set on its Wikipedia page (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure). A more detailed introduction to disjoint-set data structures call be found in the book "Introduction to Algorithms" Chapter 21 (as also shown in Reference 1 of the Wikipedia page.)

Usually when we talk about disjoint-set data structures, we are talking about a specific implementation called "disjoint-set forest". What is good about this specific implementation is that: 1) it is really easy to implement 2) has a perfect time complexity (almost constant).

You can also find some pseudocode of how to implement disjoint-set forest in the Wikipedia page or in Chapter 21 of the book I've mentioned.

Comment: You can add hyperlinks with the globe/arrow button in the markup toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://berkeley.intel-research.net/arahimi/connected/ and http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=5F7A5FE1F4DCBA968A0B0E99B0593F71?doi=10.1.1.2.5996&rep=rep1&type=pdf