# Using Python, is there a way to automatically detect a box of pixels in an image?

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library, detection

I dont currently have access to openCV on the box I am working on - which would make this a walk in the park and save me from pulling my hair - but below is an image I have that i've gotten the threshold of and what I'd like to do is find a way to get a 4-list tuple of a box around the grouping of pixels.

original threshold image[image: original threshold image]

Currently i use this code:

```
box = image.getbbox()
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(area) # Create a draw object
draw.rectangle(area.getbbox(), outline="red")
```

result image[image: result image]

But what's i'd really like to do is either draw a box around the top white area or the center grey area. I'd like to avoid cropping since I'd like to write this as an automated function and I never know where the threshold will be at. here is an example situation image i'd like to achieve that i did in fireworks:

new dream result[image: new dream result]
Hopefully that is clear! Haven't slept in two days! any pointers or guidance is mega-appreciated!

Comment: It is not completely clear. Can you actually include the walk-in-park code that you would do with OpenCV to achieve that ? I have two problems with your final image: 1) the bounding boxes are not tight, is there any reason they are padded like that ? 2) how did you decide to group certain regions in the same bounding box ?. Furthermore, you never mention it, but it seems you also want to discard small components. It is certainly possible to do this without OpenCV (I guess you don't want to use scipy either ? And PIL acts only as the image reader), but you need to better describe what you want.

Comment: Yes, i'd love to discard the smaller area blobs and only get a bounding box for the big grouping of pixels. I dont mind if the bounding boxes arent super tight, I'd like to just target that circle of interest, primarily that group of grey pixels in the center or if eaiser the group of whiteish pixels in the top right.

Comment: Fine, but you skipped the most important question. What is your criteria for grouping points in the same bounding box ?

Comment: Hi mmgp! I'd like to draw a box around groups of white/grey pixels [1] splotches that are found in the sea of black pixels [0].

Comment: I understood that. But you are not doing that. Consider the white regions at the top right corner. They are not all connected, yet they are all under the same bounding box. What was the criteria to group all those in the same bounding box ?

Comment: Ahh I follow you now mmgp! I updated the dream result image: http://i.stack.imgur.com/7aVhe.jpg   - which now shows a tighter bounding box around a contiguous set of white pixels.

Comment: That top bounding box is very clear now, but the other bounding box is still around disconnected regions. I might propose something later.

Comment: Thank you mmgp! I actually wouldnt mind if I could just find one glob and ignore the rest. For the scope of what im trying to find i'd trying my best to determine just one area even if there are others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The basic tools/values required for the task are:

- A connected component labeling method;
- Thresholds for determining whether to discard or keep a connected component;
- A metric for calculating the distance between connected components and a threshold for determining whether to join they or not (this is required only if you actually want do such thing, which is still unclear).

The first is not available on `PIL`, but `scipy` provides it. If you don't want to use `scipy` too, consider the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14350691/1832154. I've used the code at that answer, adapted it to use `PIL` images instead of plain lists, and assumed the functions present there were placed in a module called `wu_ccl`. For the third step I used the simple chessboard distance in an `O(n^2)` fashion.

Then, discarding components with less than 200 pixels, considering that components closer than 100 pixels should be in the same bounding box, and padding the bounding box in 10 pixels, this is what we get:

[image]

You could simply change the component threshold to a higher value in order to keep only the largest one. Also, you could do the two steps mentioned before this image in a reverse order: first join close components, then discard (but this is not done in the code below).

While these are relatively simple tasks, the code is not so short since we are not relying on any library for doing the tasks. Following is an example code that achieves the image above, the merging of connected components is particularly big, I guess writing it in a rush gave a code much larger than needed.

```
import sys
from collections import defaultdict
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw

from wu_ccl import scan, flatten_label


def borders(img):
    result = img.copy()
    res = result.load()
    im = img.load()
    width, height = img.size

    for x in xrange(1, width - 1):
        for y in xrange(1, height - 1):
            if not im[x, y]: continue
            if im[x, y-1] and im[x, y+1] and im[x-1, y] and im[x+1, y]:
                res[x, y] = 0
    return result

def do_wu_ccl(img):
    label, p = scan(img)
    ncc = flatten_label(p)
    # Relabel.
    l = label.load()
    for x in xrange(width):
        for y in xrange(height):
            if l[x, y]:
                l[x, y] = p[l[x, y]]
    return label, ncc

def calc_dist(a, b):
    dist = float('inf')
    for p1 in a:
        for p2 in b:
            p1p2_chessboard = max(abs(p1[0] - p2[0]), abs(p1[1] - p2[1]))
            if p1p2_chessboard < dist:
                dist = p1p2_chessboard
    return dist


img = Image.open(sys.argv[1]).convert('RGB')
width, height = img.size
# Pad image.
img_padded = Image.new('L', (width + 2, height + 2), 0)
width, height = img_padded.size
# "discard" jpeg artifacts.
img_padded.paste(img.convert('L').point(lambda x: 255 if x > 30 else 0), (1, 1))

# Label the connected components.
label, ncc = do_wu_ccl(img_padded)

# Count number of pixels in each component and discard those too small.
minsize = 200
cc_size = defaultdict(int)
l = label.load()
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        cc_size[l[x, y]] += 1
cc_filtered = dict((k, v) for k, v in cc_size.items() if k > 0 and v > minsize)

# Consider only the borders of the remaining components.
result = Image.new('L', img.size)
res = result.load()
im = img_padded.load()
l = label.load()
for x in xrange(1, width - 1):
    for y in xrange(1, height - 1):
        if im[x, y] and l[x, y] in cc_filtered:
            res[x-1, y-1] = l[x, y]
result = borders(result)
width, height = result.size
result.save(sys.argv[2])
# Collect the border points for each of the remainig components.
res = result.load()
cc_points = defaultdict(list)
for x in xrange(width):
    for y in xrange(height):
        if res[x, y]:
            cc_points[res[x, y]].append((x, y))
cc_points_l = list(cc_points.items())

# Perform a dummy O(n^2) method to determine whether two components are close.
grouped_cc = defaultdict(set)
dist_threshold = 100 # pixels
for i in xrange(len(cc_points_l)):
    ki = cc_points_l[i][0]
    grouped_cc[ki].add(ki)
    for j in xrange(i + 1, len(cc_points_l)):
        vi = cc_points_l[i][1]
        vj = cc_points_l[j][1]
        kj = cc_points_l[j][0]
        dist = calc_dist(vi, vj)
        if dist < dist_threshold:
            grouped_cc[ki].add(kj)
            grouped_cc[kj].add(ki)
# Flatten groups.
flat_groups = defaultdict(set)
used = set()
for group, v in grouped_cc.items():
    work = set(v)
    if group in used:
        continue
    while work:
        gi = work.pop()
        if gi in flat_groups[group] or gi in used:
            continue
        used.add(gi)
        flat_groups[group].add(gi)
        new = grouped_cc[gi]
        if not flat_groups[group].issuperset(new):
            work.update(new)

# Draw a bounding box around each group.
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
bpad = 10
for cc in flat_groups.values():
    data = []
    for vi in cc:
        data.extend(cc_points[vi])
    xsort = sorted(data)
    ysort = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1])
    # Padded bounding box.
    bbox = (xsort[0][0] - bpad, ysort[0][1] - bpad,
            xsort[-1][0] + bpad, ysort[-1][1] + bpad)
    draw.rectangle(bbox, outline=(0, 255, 0))
img.save(sys.argv[2])
```

Again, the function `wu_ccl.scan` need to be adjusted (taken from the mentioned answer), and for doing that consider creating an image with mode `'I'` inside it instead of using nested Python lists. I also did a slight change to `flatten_label` so it returns the number of connected components (but it is not actually used in this final code presented).

Comment: Thats awesome thank you for taking the time to cook this up mmgp - you are a king cobra of python! Im gonna plug it in and see if I can make magic happen. I wish i could upvote yah 10 times!

Answer (score 0):

If it is still of some help, there is `scipy.ndimage.measurements.label`, which finds blobs in images and can be used to find bounding box.

Comment: I didn't have time to detail it right now, but if you'd like to elaborate on this, possibly with working code, please write a comment.

Comment: Can you elaborate this?

Comment: @SaiKrishnadas Take a look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected-component_labeling